# Error during install datagrid librairie with Nuxt3

Tags: javascript, npm, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I have a Nuxt3 project and I’m trying to add a library called “@revolist/vue3-datagrid”. I ran the command “npm i @revolist/vue3-datagrid --save” as indicated in the library’s documentation. However, since the documentation explains the installation for Vue 3 and not Nuxt3, I’m not sure how to finish configuring my Nuxt3 app for this library. I’m stuck because I get an error when running npm i which is the following: ERROR self is not defined at directory/my_project/node_modules/@revolist/vue3-datagrid/dist/vgrid.js:1:522. Can anyone help me solve this issue?”

I tried to solve my problem first by adding in the nuxt.config.js '@revolist/vue3-datagrid' in the modules part but it still doesn't work. And after I added in the plugins directory the following file called 'datagrid.js' :

```
import { VGrid } from "@revolist/vue3-datagrid";

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
    nuxtApp.vueApp.use(VGrid, {})
})
```

Comment: Looks like it has a compatible issue with Nuxt 3
https://github.com/revolist/vue3-datagrid/issues/15

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this method:
**plugin/grid.client.ts**

```
import {VGridPlugin} from "@revolist/vue3-datagrid";
export default defineNuxtPlugin(async (nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(VGridPlugin)
});
```

in page or component .vue

```
<ClientOnly>
  <vue-data-grid theme="compact" :source="rows" :columns="columns" />aa
</ClientOnly>
```